# How the Java program with inheritance should be traced?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, private, public

I am looking for a way to explain how the following Java program should be traced (which method is called, etc), esp how the access modifier & inheritance affects the method invocation.

I have two classes A and B, where B extends A.
Class A has private method `process()` 
Class B has public method `process()`
Class A has public method `callProcess()` which calls `process()`.
In the main program, I create an object B and call method `callProcess()`.

```
class A {
    private void process(){
        System.out.println("Process A.");
    }
    public void callProcess(){
        process();
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public void process(){
        System.out.println("Process B.");
    }
}
class MethodTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B b1 = new B();
        b1.callProcess();
    }
}
```

I expect that the `process()` from B is invoked since the object that calls `process()` is of type B, but what happens is `process()` from A is invoked.
What's weirder is if I change the modifier of `process()` in A to public then the `process()` in B is invoked.

Comment: You are creating an object of class B, and calling the function b1.callProcess() which is Public on class A. the call gets executed and the process() method in class A gets called, as thats the private function with the signature, hence not been overridden by extended class B. When you change the modifier for method process() in class A, that exactly matches the signature of method process() in class B, the inherited class method will take priority, hence when you call again, the method b1.callProcess() , the process() method in class B gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Since `process` from `A` is a `private` method, `B` is completely unaware of its existence and it cannot be overridden.

Similarly, when you call `callProcess` on an instance of `B`, it calls `A.callProcess` (since it was not overridden in `B`). `A` only knows of its own `process` method (which cannot be overridden) and calls that.

If you were to change the visibility of the `process` method in `A` to be either `public` or `protected`, then it can be overridden in `B`, as long as the signature matches i.e. they must have the same visibility.

Comment: So, why does when process() is overridden in B, the it does not invoke process() in A still?

Comment: In your code, `process` is *not* overridden in `B`. Private methods *cannot* be overridden and in fact subclasses don't even know that they exist. If you have a private method in a parent class and a public method in a subclass, they may as well have totally separate names and signatures. They are totally distinct. `protected` or `public` methods *can* be overridden. When you change the signature of `A.process` to be `public`, it matches the signature of that of `B.process` and is therefore overridden, so `B.callProcess` calls the overridden `process` method.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for the override to be implicit, the overrided method cannot have a more restrictive access level than the overriding one.